# DRY in ActiveJob::Base

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activejob

I need to use sanitization in Jobs, so i wrote method

```
  def sanitized_sql_statement(query)
    ActiveRecord::Base.send(
        :sanitize_sql_array,
        query
    )
  end
```

I have 2 different job files. Where I should place this method and how to use it from Jobs?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `concern`.
create concerns directory under jobs directory `app/jobs/concerns` like models and controllers do.

write concern file.

```
module SqlSanitizer
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def sanitized_sql_statement(query)
    ActiveRecord::Base.send(
      :sanitize_sql_array,
      query
    )
  end
end
```

And include in your job

```
class YourJob < ActiveJob::Base
  include SqlSanitizer

  # ... do something
end
```

If you fail to auto load SqlSanitizer, add autoload path in config/application.rb file => `config.autoload_paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/jobs/concerns"`

Comment: I hot an error `NameError (uninitialized constant NotifierJob::SqlSanitizer):` Its not working in with ActiveJob

Comment: @MaxPaprikas How about include like this `include ::SqlSanitizer`. If concern file is not loaded, add path in config file `config.autoload_paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/jobs/concerns"`

Comment: Works great! Please add info about autoload to answer (autoload did the trick)